# Bezier curve method drawing wrong in java

Tags: java, matrix, bezier

Basically i have made code to draw Bezier curves but there is something wrong with it, it is not drawing how its suposed to. Core of this code should be correct, it was from one of my clases.

```
public class Bezier {

double[][] pointsY;
double[][] pointsX;
double t;

public Bezier(double[][] pointsX, double[][] pointsY, double t) {
    this.pointsY = pointsY;
    this.pointsX = pointsX;
    this.t = t;
}


    public void drawCurveNormalize (G_Graphics graphic){


        double[][] constants = {{1,0,0,0},
                                {-3,3,0,0},
                                {3,-6,3,0},
                                {-1,3,-3,1} };

        t = 1/t;
        double[][] tValues = {{1,t,t*t,t*t*t}};
       
        double[][] multiX = Util.matrixMultiplication(constants,pointsX);


        double[][] multiY = Util.matrixMultiplication(constants,pointsY);
        double[][] multi1;
        double[][] multi2;
        int dY = 0;
        int dX = 0;


        int xBeginning = (int)pointsX[0][0];
        int yBeginning = (int)pointsY[0][0];

        /*graphic.DDA(pointsX[0][0],pointsY[0][0],pointsX[1][0],pointsY[1][0],G_Color.G_cBlack);
        graphic.DDA(pointsX[1][0],pointsY[1][0],pointsX[2][0],pointsY[2][0],G_Color.G_cBlack);
        graphic.DDA(pointsX[2][0],pointsY[2][0],pointsX[3][0],pointsY[3][0],G_Color.G_cBlack);*/


        for (double i = t; i < 1; i+=t) {
            double z = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                tValues[0][j] = z;
                z = z*i;
            }

            multi1 = Util.matrixMultiplication(tValues,multiX);
            dX = (int)multi1[0][0];

            multi2 = Util.matrixMultiplication(tValues,multiY);
            dY = (int)multi2[0][0];

            graphic.DDA(xBeginning,yBeginning,dX,dY,G_Color.G_cBlack);
            xBeginning = dX;
            yBeginning = dY;
        }

}
```

input points are here

```
    double pointsX[][] = new double[][]
        {       {10},
                {100},
                {100},
                {350},
        };
    double pointsY[][] = new double[][]
            {       {10},
                    {10},
                    {200},
                    {200},
            };


Bezier bezier = new Bezier(pointsX, pointsY,10);
```

and it drawes this

[image: and it drawes this]

but it should draw betwen those lines
[image: but it should draw betwen those lines]

also here is my code for MatrixMultiplication

```
public static double[][] matrixMultiplication(double[][] matrix1, double[][] matrix2) {
    if (matrix1[0].length != matrix2.length) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Matrix column/row fail");
    }

    double[][] matrixRet = new double[matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[0].length; j++) {
            matrixRet[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < matrix1[0].length; k++) {
                matrixRet[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

   return matrixRet;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](reproducible example), please? I tried compiling your code but it does not find the `G_Graphics` class. Also, is the matrix multiplication inside a `Util` class?

Comment: Note that numerical arrays in Java already get initialized to zeroes, so you don't need that first double-for loop. Having said that: did you test your matrix multiplication code? Because either you have and you know it's not part of the problem, or you haven't and you should probably first check whether it even works properly =) Having said that, the T matrix needs to be computed _for every step_, because that's your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing in in each for loop but little bid differently problem was that in that code i was doing j < 3 instead of j < 4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this code:

```
t = 1/t;
double[][] tValues = {{1,t,t*t,t*t*t}};
...
for (double i = t; i < 1; i+=t) {
  ...
}
```

That `tValues` matrix is a variable, it needs to be *recomputed* every time you compute a point for a new `t` value. And that `t` value should definitely not be stored at the object level, and *super definitely* not get inverted any time you run your draw function. As your loop variable, keep it local to your `for` loop. At best, store your `step` size at the object level.

```
beginDrawing(); // whatever is your API's equivalent of this

double[][] xVal, yVal;
for(double t=0, step=0.01; t<1.0; t+=step) {
  double[][] tValues = {{1,t,t*t,t*t*t}};

  // get the x coordinate **for this t value**
  xVal = Util.matrixMultiplication(tValues, multiX);

  // get the y coordinate **for this t value**
  yVal = Util.matrixMultiplication(tValues, multiY);

  addVertex(xVal[0][0], yVal[0][0]);  // or equivalent
}

endDrawing();  // or equivalent
```

Comment: i was doing in in each for loop but little bid differently problem was that in that code i was doing j < 3 instead of j < 4.

Comment: The `t = 1/t;` bit seemed strange to me too. @DavidAugusta, is this answer a solution to your problem? If yes, consider accepting it, please.